# How much secure is the S3 put command method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I need to transfer some data into AWS S3. I found that I can easily transfer that with AWS CLI/SDK commands using the S3 put command. But I would like to inquire how secure it is, using this method. Is this S3 put method secure enough to send confidential/sensitive data? What protocol are they using to transfer the data?

Comment: During execution of aws command, you can use `--debug true` to view logs that shows what is happing behind the scene. Such as protocol used, in transit and at rest encryptions.

Answer (score 0):

S3 endpoints can be accessed using either HTTP or HTTPS protocols as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html). By [default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/index.html) AWS CLI will use HTTPS:

> By default, the AWS CLI uses SSL when communicating with AWS services. For each SSL connection, the AWS CLI will verify SSL certificates.

What's more you can enforce the use of HTTPS on your bucket using the [bucket policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-bucket-policies-and-apply-defense-in-depth-to-help-secure-your-amazon-s3-data/) (example):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1504640911349",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1504640908907",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If this is not enough you can use [client-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html) to encrypt your files before uploading them to S3.